# Easy parallelisation

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I often find myself writing simple for loops to perform an operation to many files, for example:

```
for i in `find . | grep ".xml$"`; do bzip2 $i; done
```

It seems a bit depressing that on my 4-core machine only one core is getting used.. is there an easy way I can add parallelism to my shell scripting?

EDIT: To introduce a bit more context to my problems, sorry I was not more clear to start with!

I often want to run simple(ish) scripts, such as plot a graph, compress or uncompress, or run some program, on reasonable sized datasets (usually between 100 and 10,000). The scripts I use to solve such problems look like the one above, but might have a different command, or even a sequence of commands to execute.

For example, just now I am running:

```
for i in `find . | grep ".xml.bz2$"`; do find_graph -build_graph $i.graph $i; done
```

So my problems are in no way bzip specific! (Although parallel bzip does look cool, I intend to use it in future).

Comment: Just a note, but you can use xargs to not have to write a loop like that:

find . | grep ".xml.bz2$" | xargs -n1 bzip2

(the -n1 says only pass each bzip 1 argument, by default xargs passes all to a single process). Unfortunately xargs does each process serially.

Comment: You should be doing `find . -name \*.xml.bz2` instead of `find . | grep ".xml.bz2$"` - that's precisely what find is for!  (Also, your regex will match filenames such as foozxmlzbz, but that's a different and unimportant issue).

Comment: Wait Evan, xargs has an argument marked "-P" for me, for number of processes!

So:
     find . | grep ".xml.bz2$" | xargs -n1 -P3 bzip2
does what I want

How long has xargs had that for??

Comment: haha i was too late with my answer. you've figured it out before me :p

Comment: lol, I had no idea xargs has a -P option! litb you get my vote for turning my little comment into a solid answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had to solve the problem today you would probably use a tool like GNU Parallel (unless there is a specialized parallelized tool for your task like `pbzip2`):

```
find . | grep ".xml$" | parallel bzip2
```

To learn more:

- Watch the intro video for a quick introduction:
  https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1
- Walk through the tutorial (man parallel_tutorial). You command line
  with love you for it.

Comment: Updated answer, this is better nowadays!

Answer (score 14):

**Solution**: Use `xargs` to run in parallel (don't forget the `-n` option!)

```
find -name \*.xml -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 3 bzip2
```

Comment: I'll give you the tick, as I'm sure this is the best answer :)

Answer (score 6):

[This perl program](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=651934) fits your needs fairly well, you would just do this:

```
runN -n 4 bzip2 `find . | grep ".xml$"`
```

Comment: Oftentimes running more than 4 can increase performance if you have 4 processors.  The fifth and higher jobs can jump in when one of the others is waiting for I/O.

Comment: Good point—on the other hand, the four processes *competing* for I/O and cache lines can sometimes slow down the total process.

Answer (score 4):

gnu make has a nice parallelism feature (eg. -j 5) that would work in your case.  Create a Makefile

```
%.xml.bz2 : %.xml


all: $(patsubt %.xml,%xml.bz2,$(shell find . -name '*.xml') )
```

then do a

```
nice make -j 5
```

replace '5' with some number, probably 1 more than the number of CPU's.  You might want to do 'nice' this just in case someone else wants to use the machine while you are on it.

Comment: I was gonna suggest using make. But you beat me to it =)

Comment: @gnud, I am interested in how you would write the makefile (if it's different from this).

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the general question is difficult, because it depends on the details of the things you are parallelizing. 
On the other hand, for this specific purpose, you should use pbzip2 instead of plain bzip2 (chances are that pbzip2 is already installed or at least in the repositories or your distro).  See here for details: http://compression.ca/pbzip2/

Answer (score 2):

I find this kind of operation counterproductive. The reason is the more processes access the disk at the same time the higher the read/write time goes so the final result ends in a longer time. The bottleneck here won't be a CPU issue, no matter how many cores you have.

Haven't you ever performed a simple two big file copies at the same time on the same HD drive? I is usually faster to copy one and then another.

I know this task involves some CPU power (bzip2 is demanding compression method), but try measuring first CPU load before going the "challenging" path we all technicians tend to choose much more often than needed.

Comment: Using the 'runN' script below, if I run 3 copies, I get a 2x speed-up (at 4 copies, is starts to slow down again), so it seems it is worth doing :)

Comment: Ok, so this time the "challenging" path really pays off

Comment: Some systems deal with concurrent disk accesses better (LOTS better!) than others.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191/how-to-obtain-good-concurrent-read-performance-from-disk

Answer (score 2):

I did something like this for bash.  The parallel make trick is probably a lot faster for one-offs, but here is the main code section to implement something like this in bash, you will need to modify it for your purposes though:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Replace NNN with the number of loops you want to run through
# and CMD with the command you want to parallel-ize.

set -m

nodes=`grep processor /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l`
job=($(yes 0 | head -n $nodes | tr '\n' ' '))

isin()
{
  local v=$1

  shift 1
  while (( $# > 0 ))
  do
    if [ $v = $1 ]; then return 0; fi
    shift 1
  done
  return 1
}

dowait()
{
  while true
  do
    nj=( $(jobs -p) )
    if (( ${#nj[@]} < nodes ))
    then
      for (( o=0; o<nodes; o++ ))
      do
        if ! isin ${job[$o]} ${nj[*]}; then let job[o]=0; fi
      done
      return;
    fi
    sleep 1
  done
}

let x=0
while (( x < NNN ))
do
  for (( o=0; o<nodes; o++ ))
  do
    if (( job[o] == 0 )); then break; fi
  done

  if (( o == nodes )); then
    dowait;
    continue;
  fi

  CMD &
  let job[o]=$!

  let x++
done

wait
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could to the following

> ```
> for i in `find . | grep ".xml$"`; do bzip2 $i&; done
> ```

But that would spin off however many processes as you have files instantly and isn't an optimal as just running four processes at a time.

Comment: This would be OK for small jobs, but I was running the above command on about 5,000 files. I suspect that would kill my computer stone dead! :)

Comment: It would drown other processes, but the Linux scheduler is pretty good at making sure processes don't get completely starved.  The issue here is memory usage, since paging will really kill performance.

Comment: I personally like this answer because it works without any extra tools being installed. It would work well in a situation where you are launching less file searches.